# Can Installing a squid 3 proxy server cause problems with my internet access?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid, http-proxy

I live on a campus that provides Internet access through squid http proxy. We need to authenticate to access the Internet. This means that I can login from only one machine at a time and cannot access Internet from multiple machines using same login ID. I devised a workaround to this problem. I installed another squid proxy server on one of my machines `A` that is always on and has a static local IP. Now I could configure my other machines to use this proxy instead without any authentication and thus I was able to achieve what I wanted.

However, after some time I started getting problems on my machine `A`. Internet connection became really slow and would often disconnect. Other machines accessing Internet through this machine would often get `Proxy is refusing connections` on firefox. Now I don't know if the two things are related and I'd like to find out.

Also I'd like to find out how can I debug this issue ?

(I am using Ubuntu 11.04)

Comment: @Ken White : Should I delete it form here and repost it in superuser ? Because it is taking too much time for move.

Comment: Hang on a few. I'll flag it for the moderators to look at; maybe we can get it moved faster.

Answer (score 0):

> "Other machines accessing Internet through this machine would often
>   get Proxy is refusing connections on firefox"

Often? That's odd, the error suggests the IP:proxy you're trying to connect is not listening so... It can only mean the wrong port was typed or squid process is really not running!

Maybe the process is "dying" at some point, make sure its running and tail (-f) cache.log to see if you're getting any errors!